# Wrong plot for Ids for output characteristics (MOSFET), does new graph look reasonable?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, matlab

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of 'Wrong graphs for Ids'. That one focuses on the transfer characteristics, while this one addresses the output characteristics. This distinction was also mentioned in the replies when asked if it was a duplicate.

EDIT: Using the feeback, I have now obtained this graph. I'm a little suspicios about faulty calculations for Vds = 10. Does the graph look reasonable?

[image: Output]

This is how I have modified my calcuation process:

```
% For Vgs = 1.5V
Ids15_calc_model = arrayfun(@(x) computeIds(x, 1.5, K_value_model, VT_value_model), Vds15);
Ids15_calc_data = arrayfun(@(x) computeIds(x, 1.5, K_measured, VT_measured), Vds15);

% For Vgs = 3V
Ids3_calc_model = arrayfun(@(x) computeIds(x, 3, K_value_model, VT_value_model), Vds3);
Ids3_calc_data = arrayfun(@(x) computeIds(x, 3, K_measured, VT_measured), Vds3);

% For Vgs = 4.5V
Ids45_calc_model = arrayfun(@(x) computeIds(x, 4.5, K_value_model, VT_value_model), Vds45);
Ids45_calc_data = arrayfun(@(x) computeIds(x, 4.5, K_measured, VT_measured), Vds45);

function Ids = computeIds(Vds, Vgs, K, VT)
    if Vds < (Vgs - VT)
        % Triode region
        Ids = K * (2 * (Vgs - VT) * Vds - Vds^2);
    else
        % Saturation region
        Ids = K * (Vgs - VT)^2;
    end
end
```

END OF EDIT

I want to obtain a similar graph to this, but for output characteristics:
[image: TRANSFER]

I have this raw data:

> ```
> % Vgs = 1.5V
> Vds15 = [0.091 0.187 0.285 0.384 0.484 0.584 0.684 0.784 0.884 0.984 1.484 1.984 2.484 2.984 3.484 3.984 4.484 4.984 5.484 5.984];
> Ids15 = [69.4*1e-6 112*1e-6 131*1e-6 138*1e-6 140*1e-6 141*1e-6 142*1e-6 143*1e-6 143*1e-6 143*1e-6 145*1e-6 146*1e-6 147*1e-6 148*1e-6 148*1e-6 149*1e-6 150*1e-6 150*1e-6 151*1e-6 151*1e-6];
> ```

> ```
> % Vgs = 3V
> Vds3 = [0.0756 0.154 0.234 0.315 0.397 0.481 0.694 0.794 0.894 0.994 1.49 1.994 2.494 2.994 3.494 3.995 4.495 4.995 5.495 5.995];
> Ids3 = [218*1e-6 429*1e-6 629*1e-6 815*1e-6 988*1e-6 1.15*1e-3 1.47*1e-3 1.58*1e-3 1.67*1e-3 1.74*1e-3 1.88*1e-3 1.92*1e-3 1.93*1e-3 1.95*1e-3 1.96*1e-3 1.97*1e-3 1.97*1e-3 1.98*1e-3 1.99*1e-3 1.99*1e-3];
> ```

> ```
> % Vgs = 4.5V
> Vds45 = [0.068 0.137 0.208 0.279 0.493 0.5920 0.691 0.790 0.889 0.989 1.487 1.986 2.486 2.986 3.486 3.986 4.486 4.986 5.486 5.986];
> Ids45 = [295*1e-6 589*1e-6 878*1e-6 1.16*1e-3 1.95*1e-3 2.29*1e-3 2.60*1e-3 2.9*1e-3 3.18*1e-3 3.44*1e-3 4.42*1e-3 4.92*1e-3 5.11*1e-3 5.18*1e-3 5.22*1e-3 5.25*1e-3 5.27*1e-3 5.29*1e-3 5.30*1e-3 5.31*1e-3];
> ```

This is also a plot of the raw data:
[image: Raw data]

I have already obtained the K and Vt value from both the measured data, and Shockley's diode model.

My solution involves determining the operating region of the MOSFET based on the measured data. Once the region is identified, I use the corresponding equation to calculate IDS. Below is the MATLAB code I've written to implement this:

```
Ids15_calc_model = K_value_model* (2 * (1.5 - VT_value_model) * Vds15 - Vds15.^2);
Ids3_calc_model = K_value_model * (2 * (3 - VT_value_model) * Vds3 - Vds3.^2);
Ids45_calc_model = K_value_model * (4.5 - VT_value_model)^2;

%Beräkna uppmätt värde
Ids15_calc_data = K_measured * (2 * (1.5 - VT_measured) * Vds15 - Vds15.^2);
Ids3_calc_data = K_measured * (2 * (3 - VT_measured) * Vds3 - Vds3.^2);
Ids45_calc_data = K_measured * (4.5 - VT_measured)^2;
```

However, the resulting graph looks very wrong.
[image: Wrong graph]

Comment: The "switching point" between the triode region and the saturation region is when Vds = (Vgs - Vt).

Comment: For example, for Vgs =3V you should switch to "saturation mode" (constant current mode Id  = constant) for Vds >2V

Comment: @Hearth No, not exactly. I wrote that question in the context of transfer characteristics. Now, I'm facing issues replicating similar calculations for the output characteristics.

Comment: @G36 Thank you for your response. I have obtained a new graph, which I've included in the question. However, the measured values seem to deviate from the model for larger Vds values. Is this to be expected?

Comment: What do you mean "transfer function of output characteristics"? Your output is labeled as Vds horizontal axis for parameter Vds, a contradiction.

Comment: @TimWilliams m sorry, I don't know what you are referring to. Which output do you mean specifically?

Comment: Both the first image https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GW0X.png (title is obscured though) and the last https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GW0X.png (which says "Output Characteristics")

Comment: In the first graph, "Ids" is written on the Y-axis and "Vds" on the X-axis. The last graph has the same labels on the axes. If you are referring to the infobox, "model, Vds = XY" means that the model was computed based on the values for Vds equal to XY.